# Why Extra Padding on top of ThumbnailView?

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using Three20's TTThumbViewController. Everything works fine except for a padding on top of the thumbnail table which appears to be reserved for the navigation header, except that it takes the place right below the header. How can I get rid of this white space?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why this works for sure, but I faced the same problem and found this solution at google group.

Override `updateTableLayout` in your `TTThumbsViewController`

```
- (void)updateTableLayout 
{ 
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 0, 0, 0); 
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero; 
}
```